# What is the pythonic way to execute multiple conditions, one after the other, while showing to the user which is the first to fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements, refactoring

Let's say I have this working code:

```
def check_some_conds(args):
    assert (condA(args) or
            condB(args))

    assert condC(args)
    assert condD(args)

    return True
```

(Yeah, I know that `assert`s are bad, but please bear with me for a moment)

Now, when I'm calling this function, I can (more or less), retrive the first failed assertion by using a `except AssertionError:`, and by doing some magic with the traceback module.

However, this is not ideal because:

- `assert` is optimised-out in python
- I can't really specify an error message
- Playing with the traceback module feels hacky at best
- I still need to get a boolean return value, so catching that and then changing the return value is boilerplate code.

I'm looking for a way to:

- Run multiple conditions, mostly independant one of the other

  - Knowing that some of the functions may be long and must be tried last (here, `condD` may take seconds
  - And some of them may be async functions or just inline evaluations (`a == b`)
- return a boolean (optional)
- log a message that says `condD failed` or `nor condA or condB succeded`

If that's not really possible, please feel free to suggest partial answers to my problem

Comment: Iterating with a for on your conditions, and doing a try/except to catch the exception if so?

Comment: @roganjosh When running python in optimized mode, where `__debug__` is False, assert statements will be ignored.

Comment: Why don't you use pytest?

Comment: @FrenchMasterSword That could do it, but that would mean most of the error messages would have to be written by hand

Comment: @RamazanPolat This is actually not for running tests (if only...), but more on a live system that check some messages for spam contents. In my code, condA may refer to the age of the account, for example.

Comment: If you need custom error messages for every tested assertion, you may iterate on a list of tuples containing (to_test, "error to raise") (using a class from Python's exceptions or a custom one inheriting from one of them would be better than a simple string)

Comment: @FrenchMasterSword That's a great idea and something i definitly consider to do if there isn't any solution. However, as mentionned in the question, i'd have prefered most messages to be autogenerated, with the name of the called function of the specific condition included (`condA failed`or `a == b don't eval to True`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through your conditions and raise errors at the end:

```
fail = False
for condition in [cond1, cond2, cond3 ...]:

    if not condition(args):
        print(condition.__name__, "failed")
        fail = True
    else:
        print(condition.__name__, "succeeded")
if fail: raise ...
```

Comment: Using `condition.__name__` is something I didn't think of, hats off to you, this sounds like a great solution to my problem

Comment: However, and I'm sure you have a solution for this too, but what if the arguments changed with each condition ? I could probably pass a tuple of argulents too, but have you got a better idea ?

Comment: Add a `break` in the `if not condition`, to stay consistent with how `assert` stopped testing (if this behaviour is still wanted)

Comment: That depends on how the arguments change. If there's a high level of customization of the arguments for each condition it may just be better to pass all the arguments into each condition and deal with which ones are used inside the conditions themselves.

Comment: But a simple bool assertion such as `a == b` doesn't have a `__name__` attribute as it directly evaluates to a `bool`

Comment: Conditions have to be functions here. (which is a good thing in my opinion)

Comment: For example arguments can be a `dict` and in each condition you can just pick out the keys that you want. i.e.  `check_age` can just grab it's params using `age = args['age']`, but `check_username` can grab `args['username']`

Comment: @Primusa @frenchMasterSword Thanks a lot to both of you (if I could upvote twice...), this helped me. since I'm in a class, I can probably pass `self` to every condition (they will basically act like the dict you mentionned earlier), and yeah, i'll have to make some one_line functions. That's a tradeoff I'm willing to take